# How to make a popped-up window a top-level window in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

In QT, when a button is clicked and a window pops up, the user can still go back and click the same button (infinite times). How can I make it so that the window that pops up from the button stays on top of the other windows?
In this case, it is the "Edit" button that pops up a window.

Here is window.cpp

```
#include "window.h"
#include "editwindow.h"
#include "ui_window.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui>

Window::Window(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Window)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

ShowEdit = new QPushButton(tr("Edit"));
ShowEdit -> show();
connect(ShowEdit, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(popup()));

Remove = new QPushButton(tr("Remove"));
Remove -> show();
connect(Remove, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(ProgramRemove()));

OK = new QPushButton(tr("OK"));
OK -> show();
connect(OK, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(Saved()));

Quit = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"));
Quit -> show();
connect(Quit, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));

QLabel *tableLabel = new QLabel(tr("All Programs"));

QVBoxLayout *buttonLayout2 = new QVBoxLayout;
buttonLayout2 -> addWidget(ShowEdit);
buttonLayout2 -> addWidget(Remove);
//buttonLayout2 -> addStretch();

QHBoxLayout *buttonLayout2_2 = new QHBoxLayout;
buttonLayout2_2 -> addWidget(Quit);
buttonLayout2_2 -> addWidget(OK);

/*******************************************************************************/
/***************************Below is for Table**********************************/
/*******************************************************************************/

PTable = new QTableWidget(10, 10);

//PTable ->setHorizontalHeader(tr("Program Names"));
//inputs->setText(QString::number(row));
//PTable->setItem(row, column, inputs);

QHBoxLayout *PTableLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
PTableLayout ->addWidget(PTable);

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*------------------------construct window--------------------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

QGridLayout *SecondLayout = new QGridLayout;
SecondLayout -> addWidget(tableLabel, 0, 0);
SecondLayout -> addLayout(PTableLayout, 1, 0);
SecondLayout -> addLayout(buttonLayout2, 0, 1);
SecondLayout -> addLayout(buttonLayout2_2, 2, 0);
setLayout(SecondLayout);
setWindowTitle(tr("Settings"));
}

Window::~Window()
{
delete ui;
}

void Window :: popup()
{
EditWindow* window_3 = new EditWindow(this);
window_3->move(QPoint(550, 100));
window_3->show();
window_3->raise();
}

void Window :: closeBoth()
{
return;
}

void Window :: Saved()
{

return;
}

void Window :: ProgramRemove()
{

return;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `QDialog` is not modal which means that it does not block the input to other windows.

You can set this property by using `setWindowModality()` in `QDialog` ([Description of Modality in QT](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop)). Essentially you just do the following:

```
setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
```

Comment: I put it under `void Window :: popup()` and it ended up crashing the program. I also commented out the `window_3 -> show();`

Answer (score 3):

If `EditWindow` is a `QDialog` you can call the exec method instead of show.

From the Qt documentation:

> int QDialog::exec () [slot]
>
> Shows the dialog as a modal dialog,
>   blocking until the user closes it. The
>   function returns a DialogCode result.
>
> If the dialog is application modal,
>   users cannot interact with any other
>   window in the same application until
>   they close the dialog. If the dialog
>   is window modal, only interaction with
>   the parent window is blocked while the
>   dialog is open. By default, the dialog
>   is application modal.

This way the user can't interact with the parent window while EditWindow is open.